# How to display new line character (^J) in emacs replace query

Tags: emacs, newlines, special-characters

Say I want to replace all the new lines in my emacs buffer with the character `k` (wait for the -1, read the rest! :) ). I know I can type `M-x replace-string RET C-q C-j RET k`.
It works fine.

My problem is that the new line character, i.e. `^J` is not displayed in the replace query, I just get a new line in the query string. Instead if I try to type `C-q C-<another_char>` I get `^<another_char>`.

As I said, it works fine, but it is annoying, because it is not compact and not easily readable. Is this the default behavior in emacs? Does anybody know how to change it?

Comment: It's certainly the default behaviour.

Comment: It should show the `^J` after you accept the search string, right?  At least, mine looks like:

`Replace string ^J with:`

so you'll at least see it afterward.

Comment: true, I see it afterwards, but I would like to have it while I write.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think Emacs's behavior can be changed in the way you want. Have you thought about using regexp-replace instead? That way you could see your new lines as `\n`.